# In ASP.NET Core, does the IoC ASP Startup Class solve what the Managed Extensibility Framework solved with a catalog and container?

Tags: inversion-of-control, mef, asp.net-core-1.0, plugin-architecture

I have read this, [MEF (Managed Extensibility Framework) vs IoC/DI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108116/mef-managed-extensibility-framework-vs-ioc-di) but it is dated.  Since then MEF was [added](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Composition/) to Core.

When I look at MEF and the IoC in ASP.NET Core, I cannot tell a lot of differences for a plugin architecture.  Both "wire-up" dependencies.  If I wanted to create a plugin in a Core application using IoC (the built in IoC), why not just change my ConfigureService methods?  Is that the same as decorating imports and exports in MEF?  How is composition different here, in 2017 (close enough)?